# why web.py cant find local css?

Tags: python, html, windows, web.py

I'm trying to include css files into my code but it says files not found

I'm going through this python course and I did everything just the same. At first, it was a path issue that I think I handled it .but I keep facing an error that the css file in my computer not found. when I tried a css link it worked, and the style changed.

```
$def with (page)
$var css: CodeWizard\static\css\bootstrap.min.css CodeWizard\static\css\bootstrap-material-design.min.css

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodeWizard</title>

    $if self.css:
        $for style in self.css.split():
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$style" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        $:page
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected that the style of my page would change but it didn't. instead the following error displayed

```
127.0.0.1:6358 - - [22/Jul/2019 18:45:22] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
127.0.0.1:6358 - - [22/Jul/2019 18:45:22] "HTTP/1.1 GET /CodeWizard/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" - 404 Not Found
127.0.0.1:6359 - - [22/Jul/2019 18:45:22] "HTTP/1.1 GET /CodeWizard/static/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" - 404 Not Found
```

and I'm sure that the files are exist in the directory

Comment: You should post a reduced set of your python code, as I suspect you've not told web.py where `/CodeWizard/` is -- Just because you can see the file doesn't mean web.py will access it: That's a good thing, as it requires you to be explicit about where everything is located.

Comment: If you follow that Python course, the CSS paths should not include **CodeWizard** itself, like this:
`$var css: static/css/bootstrap.min.css static/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css`